# JSON to CSV converter-YELP Data Set-python

Tags: python, json, csv, yelp

I am interested in data mining and I would like to open and work with yelp's data. Yelp's data is in json format and in it's website it has the following code to convert json to csv. However when I open command line and write the following:

```
$ python json_to_csv_converter.py yelp_academic_dataset.json
```

I get an error. Can you help me please?

The code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Convert the Yelp Dataset Challenge dataset from json format to csv.
For more information on the Yelp Dataset Challenge please visit http://yelp.com/dataset_challenge
"""
import argparse
import collections
import csv
import simplejson as json


def read_and_write_file(json_file_path, csv_file_path, column_names):
    """Read in the json dataset file and write it out to a csv file, given the column names."""
    with open(csv_file_path, 'wb+') as fout:
        csv_file = csv.writer(fout)
        csv_file.writerow(list(column_names))
        with open(json_file_path) as fin:
            for line in fin:
                line_contents = json.loads(line)
                csv_file.writerow(get_row(line_contents, column_names))

def get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file_path):
    """Read in the json dataset file and return the superset of column names."""
    column_names = set()
    with open(json_file_path) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line_contents = json.loads(line)
            column_names.update(
                    set(get_column_names(line_contents).keys())
                    )
    return column_names

def get_column_names(line_contents, parent_key=''):
    """Return a list of flattened key names given a dict.
    Example:
        line_contents = {
            'a': {
                'b': 2,
                'c': 3,
                },
        }
        will return: ['a.b', 'a.c']
    These will be the column names for the eventual csv file.
    """
    column_names = []
    for k, v in line_contents.iteritems():
        column_name = "{0}.{1}".format(parent_key, k) if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            column_names.extend(
                    get_column_names(v, column_name).items()
                    )
        else:
            column_names.append((column_name, v))
    return dict(column_names)

def get_nested_value(d, key):
    """Return a dictionary item given a dictionary `d` and a flattened key from `get_column_names`.

    Example:
        d = {
            'a': {
                'b': 2,
                'c': 3,
                },
        }
        key = 'a.b'
        will return: 2

    """
    if '.' not in key:
        if key not in d:
            return None
        return d[key]
    base_key, sub_key = key.split('.', 1)
    if base_key not in d:
        return None
    sub_dict = d[base_key]
    return get_nested_value(sub_dict, sub_key)

def get_row(line_contents, column_names):
    """Return a csv compatible row given column names and a dict."""
    row = []
    for column_name in column_names:
        line_value = get_nested_value(
                        line_contents,
                        column_name,
                        )
        if isinstance(line_value, unicode):
            row.append('{0}'.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))
        elif line_value is not None:
            row.append('{0}'.format(line_value))
        else:
            row.append('')
    return row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Convert a yelp dataset file from json to csv."""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Convert Yelp Dataset Challenge data from JSON format to CSV.',
            )

    parser.add_argument(
            'json_file',
            type=str,
            help='The json file to convert.',
            )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    json_file = args.json_file
    csv_file = '{0}.csv'.format(json_file.split('.json')[0])

    column_names = get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file)
    read_and_write_file(json_file, csv_file, column_names)
```

Error I am getting in the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "json_to_csv_converter.py", line 122, in column_names=get_superset_of_column_names_from_file
File "json_to_csv_converter.py", line 25, in get_superset_of_column_names_from_file
for line in fin:
File "C:\Users\Bengi\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py" line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input, self_errors,decoding_table)[0]
Unicode Decode Error: 'charmap' codec cant decode byte 0X9d in position 1102: character maps to
```

Comment: You can checkout this script. https://github.com/rajbdilip/json-to-csv-converter too.

Comment: why don't you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50999768/8211404):from line 1 to line 5200000(last line)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have file encoding problem. You should put encoding='utf8' after json file open functions like: `with open(json_file_path, encoding='utf8') as fin:`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message there appears to be something wrong with your input file. It looks like `json_to_csv_converter.py` has determined that the file encoding is Windows 1252, but there is one or more invalid characters in the file, namely `'\x9d'`, which is not a valid 1252 code point.

Check that your file is properly encoded. I'd guess that the file is UTF8 encoded, but for some reason it is being processed as if it was Windows 1252. Did you edit the file?

Comment: I didn't edit the json_to_csv_converter code. First I got this code from the:  https://github.com/Yelp/dataset-examples/blob/master/json_to_csv_converter.py and I simply copy and paste the code into a python file and saved into the directory where python.exe is located. Secondly, I downloaded the yelp data set file and save it to the same directory. Thirdly, I open the command line and went to the directory where python is located and wrote the following line: python json_to_csv_converter.py yelp_academic_dataset.json and got the following error. Do you think I am doing something wrong

Comment: @BengiKoseoglu: I don't see anything that you are doing wrong. Perhaps it has something to do with the way you unzipped the data set? I don't have access to the data, so I can't tell whether there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: I tried on another computer and tried to unzipped the file in a different way, however the error remained the same. So i really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Winzip seems to mangle it somehow. I worked around this by:

- Using 7-Zip to extract the tar file.
- Editing the script to **force use of UTF-8 encoding,** like so:

  ```
  with open(json_file_path, encoding='utf8') as fin:
  ```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? In particular, can you explain what you mean by "had a problem" (what problem?) and "extracting in the right way" (what, exactly, is the right way?)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, I got the same unicode error mentioned above. Then I found out I couldn't extract the tar file in the rigth way. I couldn't extract tar file file using winzip. When I used 7-zip it worked. When you extract the tar file , you are supposed to see lots of json files that are mentioned in [link](https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge/dataset) . Afterwards while you are opening the json file to read if you use 'with open(json_file_path, encoding='utf8') as fin:' it willl work :)

Comment: Can you edit the answer with this (rather than just having it in the comments)?