# read from line to line yelp dataset by python

Tags: python, indexing, bigdata, yelp

I want to change this code to specifically read from line 1400001 to 1450000. What is modification?
file is composed of a single object type, one JSON-object per-line.
   I want also to save the output to .csv file. what should I do?

```
revu=[]
with open("review.json", 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
      for line in f:
       revu = json.loads(line[1400001:1450000)
```

Comment: revu=[]
with open("review.json", 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
      for line in f:
       revu = json.loads(line[1400001:1450000)

Comment: that is JSON per line or is the whole file JSON?

Comment: file is composed of a single object type, one JSON-object per-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is JSON per line:

```
revu=[]
with open("review.json", 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
    # expensive statement, depending on your filesize this might
    # let you run out of memory
    revu = [json.loads(s) for s in f.readlines()[1400001:1450000]]
```

if you do it on the /etc/passwd file it is easy to test (no json of course, so that is left out)

```
revu = []
with open("/etc/passwd", 'r') as f:
    # expensive statement
    revu = [s for s in f.readlines()[5:10]]

print(revu)  # gives entry 5 to 10
```

Or you iterate over all lines, saving you from memory issues:

```
revu = []
with open("...", 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 1400001 and i <= 1450000:
            revu.append(json.loads(line))

# process revu
```

To CSV ...

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def mylines(filename, _from, _to):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i >= _from and i <= _to:
                yield json.loads(line)

df = pd.DataFrame([r for r in mylines("review.json", 1400001, 1450000)])
df.to_csv("/tmp/whatever.csv")
```

Comment: thanks very much. this works for me by negilible modification:                                        
        revu = []
with open("review.json", 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 1400001 and i <= 1450000:
            revu.append(json.loads(line))

Comment: i want to seve the output to .csv file.what shoud i do?

Comment: thanks ...you are the one!https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413548/hootnot

Comment: recently I encounter this error: name 'json' is not defined!! in spite of installing ijson thought command line and this was working nice in the past!! what is happening now ???

Comment: add the import : *import json*, should do the job. You can use *cjson* by installing it: *pip install python-cjson* and import it: *import cjson as json* and change the code by replacing *loads(...)* by *decode(...)*. for *ijson* I have not an answer currently

Comment: ujson is also an option: *pip install ujson* and *import ujson as json* should be enough.

Comment: I tried yesterday again, i usally copy the code from text file and then i paste to python script to run...yesterday worked but today no!is ther e any problem in my process?what are precautions for this process?

Comment: import os
os.chdir("d:\yelp_dataset")
import pandas as pd
import ijson
def mylines(filename, _from, _to):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i >= _from and i <= _to:
                yield json.loads(line)

df = pd.DataFrame([r for r in mylines("review.json", 2550001, 2600000)])

Comment: change: *import ijson* into *import json* like the answer under *To CSV*. You have lines of JSON in your file. Use *json, cjson, ujson* like I mentioned. ijson has different applications

Comment: very nice.when i am reading from line to line yelp review dataset https://www.yelp.com/dataset   something weird is happening...must be 5200000 lines (review per line) but i can read more!!!what is this?

Comment: I use this answer for a common problem. it is fast and fabulous among other solution for reading from line to line.i want to use this from line 1 to line 5200000(the last line of the dataset). but my computer can run it this time for such a large amount of lines! I would appreciate any ideas...

Comment: @mohsendppp: since you want to load all: what is wrong with `df = pd.read_json("review.json", ,lines=True)` ?

Comment: .thanks the memory erorr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 416, in read_json
    lines=lines, chunksize=chunksize, compression=compression,
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 466,

Comment: continue ....is :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 416, in __init__
    self.data = self._preprocess_data(data)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 477, in _preprocess_data
    data = data.read()
  File "E:\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] MemoryError

Comment: @mohsendppp: how much memory does you system have ? what is the size of the file you want to load ?  Is it enough ? You did not experience problems loading parts of the file as in the original question. So, what about loading the first 25%, say 1 - 1400000 ?

Comment: thanks for you time.Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 1800 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)/4gDDR4 memory/i run the main above question and your solution for every 50 chunks without any pain!i try to do what you whant now for 1:1400000 i will report as soon as possible

Comment: @mohsendppp: you can check on memory usage by using info(): load n-records (100 or 1000) and then use `df.info()` to get information on the memoryusage of the dataframe. Multiply that by the factor of the 5200000/n and you have the memory it will consume when fully loaded

Comment: the erorr is related to" df.to_csv" as you mentioned above for entire dataset.for the 1:1400000 this command work nicely....what should i do for entire 3 gig review data to convert to .csv??

Comment: @mohsendppp if csv conversion of all is what you want, then in this case I would read it in the chunks you can handle. Name the files differently by adding a numerical extension. Only write the header when creating the first file, so add `header=False` after the first. When you have all csv files, simply concat them into 1 file